# Conversión KB GX9 a GX18

Tags: genexus

Tengo GX18 up2, quiero convertir una kb 9.0.

Luego que llego al paso Create KB me entrega el siguiente error

error: Cannot drop the database 'GX_KB_KBTestWeb', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
error: Error creating Knowledge Base
Failed: Knowledge Base Conversion
Error creating Knowledge Base

Comment: Pareceria un problema con permisos en la instancia de SQL Server que estás usando. Revisaria por ahi. En particular ¿Con V18U2 podés crear KBs nuevas en ese SQL Server?